# Different offsets for About Me on SO and SO Meta

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

On the main and Meta website the About Me block has different top offsets (218 on SO and 210 on Meta) if a user hasn't specified the current job position:

[image: StackOverflow]
[image: StackOverflow Meta]

Reproduced in Microsoft Edge (build 16257) and Mozilla Firefox 52.3.